# Immediate alerts not working for all users

Tags: alert, smtp

We have configured new farm and currently building UAT environment. Everything is going well except the immediate alerts are not working on the sites with some users , for some users it is working fine.

- I have followed different blogs to fix the issue but of no use
- I tried updating alerttemplate, restarted timer job, adjusted the immediate alerts time , checked the smtp server if the mails are hitting and they are fine.

I am out of solution and ideas here could some one help me in this issue.

Comment: If we used the non-working user's account and set the alert on example list, do this alert work ? If yes, I guess the problem maybe is in the User Profile service.

Answer (score 0):

If **all** the excepted alerts are "hitting your SMTP server," then the problem is not with SharePoint.  You'll need to diagnose what is happening after the emails hit the SMTP server.

Are all the email addresses correct?  Could they be in the users' junk folders or perhaps being filtered out by an antispam solution?

Comment: Hi Erik , We checked in spam folders and all other folders with no use as I mentioned sometimes the mails are going through to the users and some times it does't we cross checked the email addresses as well and found no issues. any other idea??